# Django Issue Setting Empty String

Tags: django, string, if-statement

I currently have a form that allows the user to edit their profile (django-profiles). The form is working great, except that I've put a switch in place for States and Provinces depending on whether ot not the user picks Canada or the US.

In my model, I have both State and Province set so that in the table there are 2 separate fields.

In my save method I have the following:

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = RegistrationFormZ(request.POST)
   ....stuff here.....
    if form.data["country"] == 'US':
      data.state = form.data["state"]
      data.provinces = None
    if form.data["country"] == 'CA':
      data.provinces = form.data["provinces"]
      data.state = None
   ....stuff here....
    data.save()

    user.first_name = form.data['first_name']
    user.last_name = form.data['last_name']
    user.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

The if statements are not working as I expected they would on save.

What's happening is that it correctly saves the value of the option that was selected (state/province) but then fails to update the opposing one to an empty value.

So for example let's say I had a user who had a Canadian address, and then updated it to the US address.  The US state gets properly saved, but province does not get updated to None.

Comment: Why not to use [cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)?

Comment: Are "US" and "CA" definitely the keys for the respective countries? And shouldn't you be calling form.save(), not data.save()? What is "data"?

Comment: Yes they are definitely the keys.

data = newform.BetaProfile(user=user)

I just didn't include it in my original post.  What I had works to save the correct state/province value, it just doesn't update the opposing one if it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more elegant way to accomplish this is using dictionaries. As an aside, are you sure your field name is provinces (plural) instead of singular? Here's an example how to do this with dictionaries, note you could add more fields for different countries without any more `if` statements and you could even write a separate getter function to return these dictionaries:

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = RegistrationFormZ(request.POST)

    ....stuff here.....

    data.state = None
    data.provinces = None

    state_field = {}
    state_field['US'] = {}
    state_field['US']['src'] = form.data['state']
    state_field['US']['dest'] = data.state

    state_field['CA'] = {}
    state_field['CA']['src'] = form.data['province']
    state_field['CA']['dest'] = data.province


    state_field[form.data['country'].upper()]['dest'] = state_field[form.data['country'].upper()]['src']

    ....stuff here....
    data.save()

    user.first_name = form.data['first_name']
    user.last_name = form.data['last_name']
    user.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```